# post array jquery serialize

Tags: jquery, arrays, post, serialization

I am trying to post a javascript array to a php page. The array has to be associative. My structure looks like this:

```
<input id="test" value="1" class="settings" />
<input id="test1" value="2" class="settings" />
```

When I create the array it is:

```
var myArray = new Array();

$(".setttings").each(function(){
     myArray[$(this).attr("id")] = $(this).val();
});
```

Now when I post that data I am just doing:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'post.php",
    data: "settings="+myArray,
});
```

The problem is that in firebug if I look at the post for settings it is empty. I need the array passed like this because I am going to take each of those settings into php and serialize them and insert them into a field in a database. That way I can pull the settings back out and unserialize to repopulate those fields. Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would recommend two changes.

First, since you want an associative array in PHP, you should use an Object, not an Array in Javascript:

```
var myObject = new Object();

$(".setttings").each(function(){
    myObject[$(this).attr("id")] = $(this).val();
});
```

Next, you want to pass it to the data section a little differently:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "post.php",
    data: {
        settings: $.param(myObject)
    }
});
```

The important part is the $.param since that converts the object into a series of parameters (suitable for a query_string).

The final thing you need to do on the server to get it working is parse it in PHP:

```
parse_str($_POST['settings'], $settings);
```

Now you can access everything in the `$settings` variable just like you could in JavaScript.

```
$settings['id'] = "value";
```

Comment: actually I have anothe question if I want to add an id to the query how would I do that. for example id=1

Comment: Do you want to add the id to the whole request? If so, just put it along side the `settings` parameter like this: `data: { settings: ... , id: 1}` Did I understand your question correctly?

Comment: thankss that worked perfectly. i was trying to add it outside of that like the way you normally would but now i understand. thanks for your time

Answer (score 3):

Just a small update to Dougs answer.

```
data: {
        settings: $.param(myObject)
    }
```

can be changed to

```
data: myObject
```

The jQuery ajax function will automatically turn your object into a string.